# Swift 3 replacingOccurrences of multiple strings

Tags: swift

I have JavaScript code that looks like the following:

`foo.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");`

Basically this strips any return carriages and new lines from my string. I'd like to do something similar in Swift 3.

I see `func replacingOccurrences(of target: String, with replacement: String, options: CompareOptions = default, range searchRange: Range<Index>? = default) -> String` is available. The problem is, this only takes one string in the `of` parameter.

Does this mean I need to call the method multiple times for each of my instances above, once for `\r\n`, once for `\n\` and once for `\r`? Is there anyway to potentially accomplish something closer to what the regex is doing instead of calling `replacingOccurrences` three times?

Comment: Note the possible values for the `CompareOptions`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `replacingOccurrences` with the option set to `regularExpression`.

```
let updated = foo.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n|\n|\r", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Note that if you're replacing with something other than `""` (e.g. `","`), you may get one for the `"\n"` and one for the `"\r"`.  There's probably a way to make the regex "greedy" to avoid this result.

Answer (score 8):

To replace non-digits you can use "\D" as a regular expression

```
let numbers = "+1(202)-505-71-17".replacingOccurrences(of: "\\D", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

You can find how to use other regular expressions [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-and-regular-expressions-syntax--cms-26387)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty easy, it's all in the documentation.

```
let noNewlines = "a\nb\r\nc\r".replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n|\n|\r", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```